# Boundary of Ahlfors n-dimensional domain measures 0

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

A domain $\Omega\subset\mathbb R^n$ is said to be an Ahlfors $n-$dimensional domain if there exists some $c>0$ such that for every $r\in (0,1]$ and every $x\in \Omega$
$$ \mathcal L^n(\Omega\cap B(x,r))\geq c\mathcal L^n(B(x,r))$$ holds (where $\mathcal L^n$ stands for Lebesgue's measure in $\mathbb R^n$). I'm asked to prove, possibly using Lebesgue's differentiation theorem, that $\mathcal L^n(\partial \Omega)=0$. I'd appreciate some hint to solve this. Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean assuming $\Omega$ is Ahlfors $n$-dimensional, that $\mathcal{L}^n(\partial \Omega)=0$?

Comment: Probably you can use the Lebesgue density theorem via a porosity argument of the type described in [this 20 Feb 2001 sci.math.research post](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math.research/c/1GZ4gTazCzs/m/Ef2MrvfO-McJ), and measurability is not an issue since the boundary is a closed set (that's also nowhere dense, since the set is open).